# Raspberry Pi 2 to arduino RF Serial link with USB to Serial TTL Converter

Tags: arduino, usb, rf, serial, raspberry-pi

This is my first question here.
I want to have a communication channel which will use a 433 MHz RF TX-RX pair. I want to use a **Raspberry Pi 2 as a transmitter** and an **Arduino Mega as a receiver**. Is it possible to **replace the usb cable** using the RF transmitter with a USB to Serial TTL Converter with the Raspberry Pi 2?
The communication would be like this :

```
Raspberry Pi 2 --> Serial (USB) port --> USB to Serial TTL Converter --> RF Transmitter --> Air --> RF Receiver --> Arduino
```

Now I dont want to program the arduino wirelessly or anything but only have the Raspberry Pi send small (extremely - about 100 bytes/sec) amounts of data from a **python code** to the arduino wirelessly.

Comment: Why used usb to TTL converter, PI got built-in TTL output. Be carefull on set a communication clock, parity,bit lengths, stop-bits.

Answer (score 1):

Here goes answer for you.

433Mhtz RF communication between Arduino and Raspberry Pi: Arduino as receiver.

http://www.homautomation.org/2014/03/02/433mhtz-rf-communication-between-arduino-and-raspberry-pi-arduino-as-receiver/